# Is it possible for any rotation in $D_n$ to reverse orientation?

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

Say, $D_4$ has edges:$1234$, then any rotation preserves orientation.

But, is it possible for any iteration of rotation element (say of: $R^i, 0\leq i\leq n$) $(R^i)^k, k\in\mathbb{Z}$ to reverse orientation, as by reflection shown below for $D_n$?

A reflection can reverse orientation; as along y-axis:
$$1234  \stackrel{T}{\longrightarrow}  2143$$
While, reflection along x-axis, gives:
$$1234  \stackrel{T}{\longrightarrow} 1342$$

Comment: ... yes. The dihedral group contains reflections, which in two dimensions are always orientation reversing

Comment: @FShrike am asking rotations.

Comment: Oh. In which case you should discern carefully between rotations, and the composition of a rotation with a reflection. A pure rotation, a member of $SO(n)$, will never reverse orientation

Comment: @FShrike Please state what object $SO(n)$ refers to.

Comment: It's one of the famous groups - wiki it. The subgroup of all orthogonal matrices with determinant $+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

All rotations in $D_n$ are powers of a single $2\pi/n$ radian rotation about the origin; and since that rotation is orientation preserving, each of those powers is also orientation preserving.